# What about LISP, if anything, makes it easier to implement macro systems?

Tags: lisp, templates, scheme, macros, common-lisp

I'm learning Scheme from the *SICP* and I'm getting the impression that a big part of what makes Scheme and, even more so, LISP special is the macro system. But, since macros are expanded at compile-time, why don't people make equivalent macro systems for C/Python/Java/whatever? For example, one could bind the `python` command to `expand-macros | python` or whatever. The code would still be portable to people who don't use the macro system, one would just expand the macros before publishing code. But I don't know of anything like that except templates in C++/Haskell, which I gather aren't really the same. What about LISP, if anything, makes it easier to implement macro systems?

Comment: "The code would still be portable to people who don't use the macro system, one would just expand the macros before publishing code." -- just to warn you, this tends not to work well. Those other people would be able to run the code, but in practice macro-expanded code is often difficult to comprehend, and usually difficult to modify. It is in effect "badly-written" in the sense that the author hasn't tailored the expanded code for human eyes, they tailored the real source. Try telling a Java programmer you run your Java code through the C preprocessor and watch what colour they turn ;-)

Comment: Macros need to execute though, at that point you're already writing an interpreter for the language.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Many Lispers will tell you that what makes Lisp special is *homoiconicity*, which means that the code's syntax is represented using the same data structures as other data. For example, here's a simple function (using Scheme syntax) for calculating the hypotenuse of a right-angled triangle with the given side lengths:

```
(define (hypot x y)
  (sqrt (+ (square x) (square y))))
```

Now, homoiconicity says that the code above is actually representable as a data structure (specifically, lists of lists) in Lisp code. Thus, consider the following lists and see how they "glue" together:

1. `(define #2# #3#)`
2. `(hypot x y)`
3. `(sqrt #4#)`
4. `(+ #5# #6#)`
5. `(square x)`
6. `(square y)`

Macros allow you to treat the source code as just that: lists of stuff. Each of those 6 "sublists" contain either pointers to other lists, or to symbols (in this example: `define`, `hypot`, `x`, `y`, `sqrt`, `+`, `square`).

---

So, how can we use homoiconicity to "pick apart" syntax and make macros? Here's a simple example. Let's reimplement the `let` macro, which we'll call `my-let`. As a reminder,

```
(my-let ((foo 1)
         (bar 2))
  (+ foo bar))
```

should expand into

```
((lambda (foo bar)
   (+ foo bar))
 1 2)
```

Here's an implementation using Scheme "explicit renaming" macros<sup>†</sup>:

```
(define-syntax my-let
  (er-macro-transformer
    (lambda (form rename compare)
      (define bindings (cadr form))
      (define body (cddr form))
      `((,(rename 'lambda) ,(map car bindings)
          ,@body)
        ,@(map cadr bindings)))))
```

The `form` parameter is bound to the actual form, so for our example, it would be `(my-let ((foo 1) (bar 2)) (+ foo bar))`. So, let's work through the example:

1. First, we retrieve the bindings from the form. `cadr` grabs the `((foo 1) (bar 2))` portion of the form.
2. Then, we retrieve the body from the form. `cddr` grabs the `((+ foo bar))` portion of the form. (Note that this is intended to grab all the subforms after the binding; so if the form were

   ```
   (my-let ((foo 1)
            (bar 2))
     (debug foo)
     (debug bar)
     (+ foo bar))
   ```

   then the body would be `((debug foo) (debug bar) (+ foo bar))`.)
3. Now, we actually build the resultant `lambda` expression and call using the bindings and body we have collected. The backtick is called a "quasiquote", which means to treat everything inside the quasiquote as literal datums, *except* the bits after the commas ("unquote").

   - The `(rename 'lambda)` means to use the `lambda` binding in force when this macro is *defined*, rather than whatever `lambda` binding might be around when this macro is *used*. (This is known as *hygiene*.)
   - `(map car bindings)` returns `(foo bar)`: the first datum in each of the bindings.
   - `(map cadr bindings)` returns `(1 2)`: the second datum in each of the bindings.
   - `,@` does "splicing", which is used for expressions that return a list: it causes the list's elements to be pasted into the result, rather than the list itself.
4. Putting all that together, we get, as a result, the list `(($lambda (foo bar) (+ foo bar)) 1 2)`, where `$lambda` here refers to the renamed `lambda`.

Straightforward, right? ;-) (If it's not straightforward for you, just imagine how difficult it would be to implement a macro system for other languages.)

---

So, you can have macro systems for other languages, if you have a way to be able to "pick apart" source code in a non-clunky way. There are some attempts at this. For example, [sweet.js](http://sweetjs.org/) does this for JavaScript.

† For seasoned Schemers reading this, I intentionally chose to use explicit renaming macros as a middle compromise between `defmacro`s used by other Lisp dialects, and `syntax-rules` (which would be the standard way to implement such a macro in Scheme). I don't want to write in other Lisp dialects, but I don't want to alienate non-Schemers who aren't used to `syntax-rules`.

For reference, here's the `my-let` macro that uses `syntax-rules`:

```
(define-syntax my-let
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((my-let ((id val) ...)
       body ...)
     ((lambda (id ...)
        body ...)
      val ...))))
```

The corresponding `syntax-case` version looks very similar:

```
(define-syntax my-let
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      ((_ ((id val) ...)
         body ...)
       #'((lambda (id ...)
            body ...)
          val ...)))))
```

The difference between the two is that *everything* in `syntax-rules` has an implicit `#'` applied, so you can *only* have pattern/template pairs in `syntax-rules`, hence it's fully declarative. In contrast, in `syntax-case`, the bit after the pattern is actual code that, in the end, has to return a syntax object (`#'(...)`), but can contain other code too.

Comment: An advantage you haven't mentioned: yes, there are attempts in other languages, such as sweet.js for JS. However, in lisps, writing a macro is done in the same language as writing a function.

Comment: Right, you can write procedural (versus declarative) macros in Lisp languages, which is what allows you to do really advanced stuff. BTW, this is what I like about Scheme macro systems: there are multiple to choose from. For simple macros, I use `syntax-rules`, which is purely declarative. For complicated macros, I can use `syntax-case`, which is partly declarative and partly procedural. And then there's explicit renaming, which is purely procedural. (Most Scheme implementations will provide either `syntax-case` or ER. I've not seen one that provides both. They're equivalent in power.)

Comment: Why do macros have to modify the AST? Why can't they work at a higher level?

Comment: @RenéG What do "higher level" macros look like, and what would they do?

Comment: What I mean is, why does having the source code already in AST-form make it easier to do macros? I still don't quite understand.

Comment: For example, why is sweet.js harder to use than LISP macros?

Comment: @RenéG sweet.js is not harder to use than Lisp macros, actually. sweet.js has two types of macros, `rule` and `case` macros, which correspond to Scheme's `syntax-rules` and `syntax-case` respectively (in a very loose sense). Both sweet.js and Scheme macros look and feel very similar.

Comment: So then why is LISP better? What makes LISP special? If one can implement macros in js, surely one can implement them in any other language as well.

Comment: @RenéG I would say that Lisp languages are not constrained by Algol-style syntax, so good macros are easier to design. What I mean is, you don't have to consider infix operators, curly brace blocks, semicolons, etc. In Lisp, there's just one uniform syntax (S-expressions), so it's easier to design macros tastefully. Of course, that's just my subjective opinion, but there is really no objective answer to "why is Lisp better". (BTW, Lisp, not LISP.)

Comment: @RenéG as I said in my first comment, a big advantage is that you're still writing in the same language.

Comment: But sweet.js IS written in Javascript. How is writing LISP macros in LISP an advantage over writing Javascript macros in Javascript?

Answer (score 24):

A dissenting opinion:  Lisp's homoiconicity is far less of a useful thing than most Lisp fans would have you believe.

To understand syntactic macros, it's important to understand compilers.  The job of a compiler is to turn human-readable code into executable code.  From a very high-level perspective, this has two overall phases: *parsing* and *code generation*.

*Parsing* is the process of reading code, interpreting it according to a set of formal rules, and transforming it into a tree structure, generally known as an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree).  For all the diversity among programming languages, this is one remarkable commonality: essentially every general-purpose programming language parses into a tree structure.

*Code generation* takes the parser's AST as its input, and transforms it into executable code via the application of formal rules.  From a performance perspective, this is a much simpler task; many high-level language compilers spend 75% or more of their time on parsing.

The thing to remember about Lisp is that it's *very, very old*.  Among programming languages, only FORTRAN is older than Lisp.  Way back in the day, parsing (the slow part of compiling) was considered a dark and mysterious art.  John McCarthy's original papers on the theory of Lisp (back when it was just an idea that he never thought could actually be implemented as a real computer programming language) describes a somewhat more complex and expressive syntax than the modern "S-expressions everywhere for everything" notation.  That came about later, when people were trying to actually implement it.  Because parsing was not well-understood back then, they basically punted on it and dumbed down the syntax into a homoiconic tree structure in order to make the parser's job utterly trivial.  The end result is that you (the developer) have to do a lot of the parser's work for it by writing the formal AST directly into your code.  Homoiconicity doesn't "make macros so much easier" as much as it makes writing everything else that much harder!

The problem with this is that, especially with dynamic typing, it's very difficult for S-expressions to carry much semantic information around with them.  When all of your syntax is the same type of thing (lists of lists), there isn't much in the way of context provided by the syntax, and so the macro system has very little to work with.

Compiler theory has come a long way since the 1960s when Lisp was invented, and while the things it accomplished were impressive for its day, they look rather primitive now.  For an example of a modern metaprogramming system, have a look at the (sadly underappreciated) Boo language.  Boo is statically typed, object-oriented, and open-source, so every AST node has a type with a well-defined structure that a macro developer can read the code to.  The language has a relatively simple syntax inspired by Python, with various keywords that give intrinsic semantic meaning to the tree structures built from them, and its metaprogramming has an intuitive quasiquote syntax to simplify the creation of new AST nodes.

Here's a macro I created yesterday when I realized I was applying the same pattern to a bunch of different places in GUI code, where I would call `BeginUpdate()` on a UI control, perform an update in a `try` block, and then call `EndUpdate()`:

```
macro UIUpdate(value as Expression):
    return [|
        $value.BeginUpdate()
        try:
            $(UIUpdate.Body)
        ensure:
            $value.EndUpdate()
    |]
```

The `macro` command is, in fact, [a macro itself](https://github.com/bamboo/boo/blob/master/src/Boo.Lang.Extensions/Macros/MacroMacro.boo), one that takes a macro body as input and generates a class to process the macro.  It uses the name of the macro as a variable that stands in for the `MacroStatement` AST node that represents the macro invocation.  The [| ... |] is a quasiquote block, generating the AST that corresponds to the code within, and inside the quasiquote block, the $ symbol provides the "unquote" facility, substituting in a node as specified.

With this, it's possible to write:

```
UIUpdate myComboBox:
   LoadDataInto(myComboBox)
   myComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0
```

and have it expand to:

```
myComboBox.BeginUpdate()
try:
   LoadDataInto(myComboBox)
   myComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0
ensure:
   myComboBox.EndUpdate()
```

Expressing the macro this way is simpler and more intuitive than it would be in a Lisp macro, because the developer knows the structure of `MacroStatement` and knows how the `Arguments` and `Body` properties work, and that inherent knowledge can be used to express the concepts involved in a very intuitive way.  It's also safer, because the compiler knows the structure of `MacroStatement`, and if you try to code something that isn't valid for a `MacroStatement`, the compiler will catch it right away and report the error instead of you not knowing until something blows up on you at runtime.

Grafting macros onto Haskell, Python, Java, Scala, etc isn't difficult because these languages aren't homoiconic; it's difficult because the languages are not designed for them, and it works best when your language's AST hierarchy is designed from the ground up to be examined and manipulated by a macro system.  When you're working with a language that was designed with metaprogramming in mind from the beginning, macros are much simpler and easier to work with!

Comment: Joy to read, thank you! Do non-Lisp macros stretch as far as changing syntax? Because one of the strength of Lisp is the syntax is all the same, thus it is easy to add a function, conditional statement, whatever because they are all the same. While with non-Lisp languages one thing differs from another -- `if...` does not look like a function call for example. I don't know Boo, but imagine Boo didn't have pattern matching, could you introduce it with its own syntax as macro? My point is -- any new macro in Lisp feels 100% natural, in other languages they work, but you can see the stitches.

Comment: The story as I have always read it is a bit different. An alternative syntax to s-expression was planned but work on it was delayed because programmers had already started to use s-expressions and found them convenient. So the work on the new syntax was eventually forgotten. Can you please cite the source that indicates the shortcomings of compiler theory as the reason for using s-expressions? Also, the Lisp family kept evolving for many decades (Scheme, Common Lisp, Clojure) and most dialects decided to stick to s-expressions.

Comment: "only FORTRAN is older than Lisp" -- Not quite. There were others around: B-0 (-> Flow-Matic -> COBOL) and IAL (-> ALGOL) spring to mind. But Lisp is certainly up there with the *really* old stuff. ;-)

Comment: "simpler and more intuitive": sorry, but I don't see how. "Updating.Arguments[0]" is *not* meaningful, I'd rather have a named argument and let the compiler check itselfs if the number of arguments matches: http://pastebin.com/YtUf1FpG

Comment: @greenoldman: [Pattern matching in Boo.](https://github.com/bamboo/boo/tree/master/src/Boo.Lang.PatternMatching)  It's implemented by a macro, as you suspected.  It's possible to create some very different syntax using macros, such as [a "parser generator" that is actually a parser](https://github.com/bamboo/boo-extensions/tree/master/src/Boo.OMeta), because macros have direct access to the AST and can rewrite it in arbitrary ways.  Inside a macro body, the parser's rules on what is allowed is relaxed in some ways, so you can enter all sorts of stuff and sort it out in the macro code.

Comment: *"From a performance perspective, this is a much simpler task; many high-level language compilers spend 75% or more of their time on parsing."* I would've expected looking for and applying optimizations to take up most of the time (but I've never written a *real* compiler). Am I missing something here?

Comment: @coredump: The system you describe is how Boo's "meta methods" work.  It's a more simplified metaprocessing system, and you can write a meta method with a well-defined signature like you're asking for, but it gives up a lot of the flexibility that comes with full macros.  Different tools for different tasks, basically.

Comment: @Doval: What you're missing is that once you have a tree--particularly an object-oriented tree with nodes of different semantic types being represented by distinct classes--searching through it for various patterns can be *very* fast by simply applying the Visitor Pattern, especially if the visitor for a certain optimization can recognize that a particular node is irrelevant and "prune" the tree search by not visiting its subnodes at all.  For example, in the Boo compiler there are 61 "pipeline steps" (also known as "passes").  Parsing takes longer than the other 60 put together.

Comment: Still, I think the next to last paragraph should be detailed: you claim that Boo macros are "more intuitive"   (you could have said: they are intuitive, but you said "more intuitive" than Lisp macros), but the explanation is a little weak (don't Lispers also know their language?). As for being more secure: (1) I am sure you can escape type safety with Boo too, and (2) there are static type checking in modern CL implementations and your own macro can signal an error if you implement more checks.

Comment: @Doval,MasonWheeler Whether parsing or optimization takes more time depends strongly on the language and the sophistication of the optimizer.  As an extreme example, enabling MSVC's link-time optimizer can *double* overall compile time for a large project!

Comment: @zwol: As I understand it--and I could be way off, so please tell me if this isn't right--but isn't that a "whole program optimization" system that compiles everything once, generates statistical data about the project, and then runs the entire compile a second time using the data to guide its optimization efforts?  That obviously would require twice as much time.

Comment: @MasonWheeler That's PGO mode, which is *even slower*.  Link-time optimization can be used without profile feedback.

Comment: A first Lisp was invented in 1958. Then a few decades of research was invested. You ignore all of that. Congratulations!

Comment: @RainerJoswig: I'm not ignoring all that; **it's my basic thesis.**  Lisp's syntax is stuck in the 1960s and it's carrying all that baggage around with it even to modern times, whereas newer languages are able to much more easily take advantage of research in compiler engineering and language design, and do the same interesting things that Lisp is capable of without being burdened with stuff like homoiconicity.

Comment: Unfortunately your example does not show that. It's primitive to implement in any Lisp with macros. Actually this is one of the most primitive macros to implement. This makes me suspect that you don't know much about macros in Lisp.  "Lisp's syntax is stuck in the 1960s": actually macro systems in Lisp have made a lot of progress since 1960 (In 1960 Lisp did not even have macros!).

Comment: @coredump: Turns out I was mistaken.  Boo macros can actually be declared with a formal argument list; it's just that this is an optional (and unfortunately not very well-documented) feature.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Please feel free to edit your answer. I don't see the need to especially advocate Boo, but that's ok. What I don't understand is the need to  gratuitously bash Lisp's with unsubstantiated and/or mistaken claims (e.g. the good ol' "something-blows-up-at-runtime" argument). You should focus on what you say in the conclusion  about exposing the AST. I'am genuinely interested to see some of the benefits of having richer code representation.

Comment: I disagree that you must understand the fine points of compiler theory before you can understand how to write a macro in Lisp. CL has the simplest macro system out there. Maybe what you say is true of Boo macros: To write them, you literally have to know all the various classes that are used to represent the AST and how they fit together. [This tutorial](http://boo.codehaus.org/Syntactic+Macros) on Boo macros shows how difficult it is. The Lisp AST only has 6 types, all of which are ordinary types such as lists, strings, and symbols, that you're already familiar with if you code in Lisp.

Comment: @ThrowawayAccount3Million: On the contrary, that tutorial illustrates the simplicity of the system, showing how you can use the Visitor Pattern to make a macro in a simple way. You don't "need to know every class and how they fit together"; just the specific types you're dealing with.  The visitor defined in the example only needs to know about one AST node type: `ReferenceExpression`; the class it inherits from takes care of all the rest of the logic of walking the AST. (more)

Comment: `ReferenceExpression` refers to a single identifier, like the name of a variable or class.  There are other node types for control structures, but in Lisp, the control structures aren't defined at the language level, so your visitor would have to have all sorts of special cases to look at every node and figure out whether it's a control structure, a method invocation, an identifier, a macro, etc etc.  With a strongly-typed, object-oriented AST you get all that for free.

Comment: Let's count the classes involved in that macro: `AbstractAstMacro`, `DepthFirstTransformer`, `ReferenceExpression`, `MemberReferenceExpression`, `MacroStatement`, and `Statement`. That's 6 classes, and there are plenty of additional classes in the AST. I have no idea when or how `OnReferenceExpression` will be called. Does control somehow end up there indirectly via `ne.Visit`? Certainly, every single time you write a macro in Boo, you need to open the Reference Manual to make sure you remember every class you need to inherit from and every method you need to override. (more)

Comment: A similar macro can be written in Lisp: http://pastebin.com/YEDzcwVj, with less than half the lines of code that it took to write the Boo version. The only thing you lose is the ability to have macros and functions whose names begin with _ (because, admittedly, Lisp macros can't tell the difference. My code literally assumes that every symbol named like `_this` is a struct member). But at least there's no spooky action at a distance in the Lisp version.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm learning Scheme from the SICP and I'm getting the impression that a big part of what makes Scheme and, even more so, LISP special is the macro system.

How so? All the code in SICP is written in macro-free style. There are no macros in SICP. Only in a footnote on page 373 are macros ever mentioned.

> But, since macros are expanded at compile-time

They aren't necessarily. Lisp provides macros in both interpreters and compilers. Thus there might not be a compile-time. If you have a Lisp interpreter, macros are expanded at execution time. Since many Lisp systems have a compiler on board, one can generate code and compile it at runtime.

Let's test that using SBCL, a Common Lisp implementation.

Let's switch SBCL to the Interpreter:

```
* (setf sb-ext:*evaluator-mode* :interpret)

:INTERPRET
```

Now we define a macro. The macro prints something when it is called for code expanded. The generated code does not print.

```
* (defmacro my-and (a b)
    (print "macro my-and used")
    `(if ,a
         (if ,b t nil)
         nil))
```

Now let's use the macro:

```
MY-AND
* (defun foo (a b) (my-and a b))

FOO
```

See. In above case Lisp does nothing. The macro is not expanded at definition time.

```
* (foo t nil)

"macro my-and used"
NIL
```

But at runtime, when the code is used, the macro is expanded.

```
* (foo t t)

"macro my-and used"
T
```

Again, at runtime, when the code is used, the macro is expanded.

Note that SBCL would expand only once when using a compiler. But various Lisp implementations also provide interpreters - like SBCL.

Why are macros easy in Lisp? Well, they aren't really easy. Only in Lisps, and there are many, which have macro support built in. Since many Lisps come with extensive machinery for macros, it looks like it is easy. But macro mechanisms can be extremely complicated.

Comment: I've been reading a lot about Scheme around the web as well as reading SICP. Also, aren't Lisp expressions compiled before they're interpreted? They at least must be parsed. So I guess "compile-time" should be "parse-time".

Comment: @RenéG Rainer's point, I believe, is that if you `eval` or `load` code in any Lisp language, macros in those will get processed too. Whereas if you use a preprocessor system as proposed in your question, `eval` and the like won't benefit from the macro expansion.

Comment: @RenéG Also, "parse" is called `read` in Lisp. This distinction is important, because `eval` works on actual the list data structures (as mentioned in my answer), not on the textual form. So you can use `(eval '(+ 1 1))` and get back 2, but if you `(eval "(+ 1 1)")`, you get back `"(+ 1 1)"` (the string). You use `read` to get from `"(+ 1 1)"` (a string of 7 characters) to `(+ 1 1)` (a list with one symbol and two fixnums).

Comment: @RenéG With that understanding, macros do not work at `read`-time. They work at compile-time in the sense that if you have code like `(and (test1) (test2))`, it will get expanded into `(if (test1) (test2) #f)` (in Scheme) just the once, when the code is loaded, rather than each time the code is run, but if you do something like `(eval '(and (test1) (test2)))`, that will compile (and macro-expand) that expression appropriately, at runtime.

Comment: @RenéG Homoiconicity is what allows Lisp languages to eval on the list structures instead of the textual form, and for those list structures to be transformed (via macros) prior to execution. Most languages' `eval` works on text strings only, and their capabilities for syntax modification are much more lacklustre and/or cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

[Homoiconicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) makes it much much easier to implement macros. The idea that code is data and data is code makes it possible to more or less (barring accidental capture of identifiers, solved by [hygienic macros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygienic_macro)) to freely substitute one for the other. Lisp and Scheme make this easier with their syntax of S-expressions which are uniformly structured and thus easy to turn into ASTs which form the basis of [Syntactic Macros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_%28computer_science%29#Syntactic_macros).

Languages without S-Expressions or Homoiconicity will run into trouble implementing Syntactic Macros though it can still certainly be done. [Project Kepler](http://scalamacros.org/) is attempting to introduce them to Scala for instance.

The largest issue with syntax macros usage aside from non-homoiconicity, is the issue of arbitrarily generated syntax. They offer tremendous flexibility and power but at the price that your source code may no longer be as easy to understand or maintain.